# motor earth wire gronding

Tags: grounding

I have to install a 1500W single phase motor 200m away from the main supply.

I have a question about how to make an earth connection to the motor.

Is it ok to earth the motor chassis with a grounding rod at the motor location itself instead of laying a 200m 10sqsmm earth cable to connect the motor chassis to the main ground rod at the main supply to save the earth cable cost?

Thank you

Comment: Depends on your local electrical rules. Consult an electrician in your area.

Comment: According to the electric code and typical practice in the USA, you can sink an extra grounding rod at the motor location and tie it to the motor chassis. But you must also use the protective earth wire all the way from the electrical installation area (near the meter or main panel or whatever).

Comment: Part of the purpose of "grounding" the motor chassis is to provide a low resistance return path for fault currents back to the source (utility company transformer). If those currents have to flow through a long patch of soil, the resistance might be to high. Another purpose is to keep the potential near earth potential. The ground rod would be effective at that second purpose, but not the first.

Comment: You may need to upsize your feed wire, depending on the voltage. Check with your local electrical inspector, he will give you an answer that will pass his inspection and be code compliant.